# Refreshing livedata with Retrofit request response

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-viewmodel

I have a simple app, which shows a list of movies. When a user clicks a button it should refresh the list, which means to go to Retrofit again and fetch the new list.
The problem is, that this refresh doesn't work. It only fetches the list once, when I open the app.

```
public class MoviesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> mLastdMovieListObservable;
    private Repository mRepository;

    public MoviesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new Repository();
    }

    public LiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> getMovieListLiveData() {
        if (mLastdMovieListObservable == null) {
            mLastdMovieListObservable = mRepository.getMovieList();
        }
        return mLastdMovieListObservable;
    }
}
```

and the Repository :

```
public MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> getMovieList() {
    final MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    data.setValue(Resource.loading(null));

    mInterface.getMovies(.....).enqueue(new Callback<MovieListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieListResponse> call, Response<MovieListResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                data.postValue(Resource.success(response.body().getResult()));
            } else {
                data.postValue(Resource.error(response.message(), null));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            data.postValue(Resource.error(t.getMessage(), null));
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Then in the fragment it's just :

```
mMoviesViewModel.getMovieListLiveData().observe(this, moviesResource -> {
    if (moviesResource.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
       .....
       .....
```

then the button click part, when I need to fetch the list again, I'm not sure how to implement it. 
Anything I tried didn't work. the Repository returned the data as null right away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use retry approach and I changed your code quickly for an example of retry and check this source for better code.[LINK](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt)

Transformations.switchMap listens to retry and when it changed, swithMap will be call again.And in UI ViewModel should be config like below but in button you need to call just retry.

```
mMoviesViewModel.getMovieListLiveData().observe(this, moviesResource -> {
if (moviesResource.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
   .....
   .....
```

And in button:

```
mMoviesViewModel.retry()
```

Also ViewModel:

```
public class MoviesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> mLastdMovieListObservable;
private Repository mRepository;
private Boolean mRetry = false;

public MoviesViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new Repository();
    mLastdMovieListObservable = Transformations.switchMap(mRetry){
        mLastdMovieListObservable = mRepository.getMovieList()
    }
}

public LiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> getMovieListLiveData() {
    return mLastdMovieListObservable;
}

public void retry(){
    mRetry.setValue(true)
}}
```

Comment: thank you, but what would you do if the request calls different types of movie based on an enum?
for example, I want getMovies(enum.Latest), or getMovies(enum.Popular).. it gets more complicated, and handling it all with a boolean seems a bit far fetched

Comment: I posted another example and it is not complex.

Answer (score 0):

Changes for movie types can be like below:

```
public class MoviesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> mLastdMovieListObservable;
private Repository mRepository;
private Int mMovieType = 0;

public MoviesViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new Repository();
    mLastdMovieListObservable = Transformations.switchMap(mMovieType, type->
        mLastdMovieListObservable = mRepository.getMovieList(type)
    );
}

public LiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> getMovieListLiveData() {
    return mLastdMovieListObservable;
}

public void setMovieType(Int movieType){
    mMovieType.setValue(movieType)
}
```

}

Comment: thank you, but as you see in my repository I use Resource, which is updated first with Loading status, and then I do setValue again for the response itself. I'm not sure will work. When you hit setMovieType, it will send the Loading, but when a response returns, it will "ignore" it.

Comment: You can change your solution for loading and have success and failure but in UI handle the loading by show indicator at first and disable it when response is success. You can find two approaches for Resource, with loading and without loading. Using loading in Resource is not definitive method and I think you need to play with code to get the result.